# Create exe for python based on anaconda including fbprophet

Tags: python

I have fbprophet already installed - and try to create an exe file for windows 10 using pyinstaller.

At first I tried a small code to see whether I know how to handle the pyinstaller syntax (without fbprophet), as you can see below

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
excel_path=sg.PopupGetFile("Select Excel file to forecast",title="Excel file to forecast",icon="Mann+Hummel.ico")
data=pd.read_excel(str(excel_path))
data["ds"]=pd.to_datetime(data["ds"])
liste=[names for names in data.columns if names != "ds"]
frequency=["D","W","MS","Q","A"]
cut_off=int(0.7*len(data.index))
minimum_periode=(int(0.3*len(data.index))+1)
#sg.ChangeLookAndFeel("GreenTan")
sg.SetOptions(text_justification="right")
layout = [[sg.Text('Fbprophet forecast Command Line Parameters', font=('Helvetica', 16))],
       [sg.Text('_'  * 100, size=(65, 1))],
       [sg.Text('External parameters', font=('Helvetica', 15), justification='left')],
       [sg.Text("Put excel sheet to analyze"),sg.Input(str(excel_path),size=(50,1))], #values[0]
       [sg.Text('_'  * 100, size=(65, 1))],
       [sg.Text('External parameters', font=('Helvetica', 15), justification='left')],
       [sg.Text("Select product",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Drop(values=liste,size=(10,1))], #values[1]
       [sg.Text("Forecast period",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Slider(range=(minimum_periode,2*minimum_periode),orientation='h',default_value=minimum_periode)],#values[2]
       [sg.Text("Observation bin",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.DropDown(values=frequency,size=(10,1))],#values[3]
       [sg.Text("Add Holidays",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.DropDown(values=frequency,size=(10,1))], #values[4]
       [sg.Text('_'  * 100, size=(65, 1))],
       [sg.Text('Fbprophet parameters', font=('Helvetica', 15), justification='left')],
       [sg.Text("Changepoint_prior_scale",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Spin(values=[i for i in np.linspace(0.05,2,10)],initial_value=0.05)], #values[5]
       [sg.Text("Changepoint_range",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Spin(values=[i for i in np.linspace(0.8,0.95,10)],initial_value=0.8)],#values[6]
       [sg.Text("n_changepoints",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Spin(values=np.arange(25,50),initial_value=25)],#values[7]
       [sg.Text('_'  * 100, size=(65, 1))],
       [sg.Text('Plotting parameters', font=('Helvetica', 15), justification='left')],
       [sg.Text("Plot Title",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Input(default_text="Title of Plot for selected",justification="left")], #values[8]
       [sg.Text("Title of y-Axis",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Input(default_text="Title of y-axis",justification="left")],#values[9]
       [sg.Text("Title of x-Axis",size=(20,1),justification="left"),sg.Input(default_text="Title of x-axis",justification="left")],#values[10]
       [sg.Submit(),sg.Cancel()]
       ]
window=sg.Window("Forecast",icon="Mann+Hummel.ico",default_element_size=(40,10)).Layout(layout)
button, values = window.Read()
window.Close()
```

I saved this script as "test.py" in a folder and after that I opened Anaconda prompt as Admin, navigated to the folder with my script and executed "pyinstaller test.py"

This works fine and I realized ok, I can go to the next step, which is including fbprophet into my script, since I would like to create a GUI for my colleagues here, who are not familiar with coding.
If I include fbprophet into my script and again execute the line "pyinstaller test.py" it executes a dist file and also an exe file. But if I open the exe file, nothing happens. I deleted all the dist and build folder and repeated - to be 100% sure that an existing dist build folders don't provoke errors and executed the line again. Again I get a exe file and if I click on it, nothing happens

So I assume the issue is due to fbprophet which works perfectly if I execute it directly. I tried several steps but without success. If you also have a different direction to create an exe file, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly an answer to the question. But it seems to be a bug with fbprophet and cxfreeze. It's not possible (at least for me) to build an exe file with fbprophet using either cx freeze or pyinstaller

If someone has an answer please let us know

Chhers